Valgrind is still showing memory is reachable with addrec()
The following code is for creating and managing hash table:
hash.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "hash.h"


typedef struct node {
    record_t rec;
    struct node *next;
} node_t;

node_t *hashArray [MAX_SIZE];

void initHashTable() {
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
        hashArray[i] = NULL;
    }
}


int myHashFunc(long long phone_num)
{
    return phone_num % MAX_SIZE;
}

int searchRecord(long long phone, record_t *record)
{
    int hix;
    node_t *ptmp;

    hix = myHashFunc(phone);
    ptmp = hashArray[hix];
    if(ptmp->rec.phone == phone){
        *record = (ptmp->rec);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    while(ptmp){
        if(ptmp->rec.phone == phone){
            *record = ptmp->rec;
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        ptmp = ptmp->next;
    }
    return NOT_FOUND_ERR;
}

int addRec(record_t *rec)
{
    int hix;
    node_t *pn = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if(pn == NULL) return NO_MEMORY_ERR;

    pn->rec = *rec;

    hix = myHashFunc(rec->phone);
    pn->next = hashArray[hix];
    hashArray[hix] = pn;

    return SUCCESS;
}

int delRec(long long phone)
{
    int hix;
    node_t *ptmp, *delnode;

    hix = myHashFunc(phone);
    ptmp = hashArray[hix];

    if(ptmp == NULL || ptmp == 0){
        return NOT_FOUND_ERR;
    }

    if(ptmp->rec.phone == phone){
        delnode = ptmp;
        hashArray[hix] = ptmp->next;
        free(delnode);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    while(ptmp->next){
        if(ptmp->next->rec.phone == phone){
            delnode = ptmp->next;
            ptmp->next = ptmp->next->next;
            free(delnode);
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        ptmp = ptmp->next;
    }
    return NOT_FOUND_ERR;
}

void displayAllRecords()
{
    int i;
    node_t *ptmp;
    printf("Name                    Phone Number\n");
    printf("--------------------    ----------\n");
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++){
        ptmp = hashArray[i];
        while(ptmp){
            printf("%19s    %10lld\n",ptmp->rec.name, ptmp->rec.phone);
            ptmp = ptmp->next;
        }
    }
}

int destroyhash()
{
    int i;
    node_t *temp, *curr;
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++){
        curr = hashArray[i];
        while(curr != NULL){
            temp = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
            free(temp);
        }
    }
}


test.c: #include <stdio.h>
#include "hash.h"
enum{SER = 1, ADD, DEL, DISP, XIT};

int main()
{
    struct record rec;
    int option, state;
    void initHashTable();
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter 1:To search and get, 2: Add a record, 3: Delete a record\n");
        printf("Enter your option: ");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        long long phone;
        switch(option)
        {
            case SER:
                printf("Enter the phone number to search\n");
                scanf("%lld",&phone);
                state = searchRecord(phone, &rec);
                if(state == SUCCESS)
                    printf("Name: %s, phone: %lld\n", rec.name, rec.phone);
                else
                    printf("Search failed with error %d\n", state);
                break;
            case ADD:
                printf("Enter phone number: \n");
                scanf("%lld",&rec.phone);
                getc(stdin);
                printf("Enter name\n");
                scanf("%[^\n]",rec.name);
                state = addRec(&rec);
                if(state == SUCCESS)
                    printf("Record added successfully\n");
                else
                    printf("Record addition failed with error %d\n", state);
                break;
            case DEL:
                printf("Enter phone number to search\n");
                scanf("%lld",&phone);
                state = delRec(phone);
                if(state == SUCCESS)
                    printf("Record deleted successfully\n");
                else
                    printf("Record deletion failed with error %d\n", state);
                break;
            case DISP:
                displayAllRecords();
                break;
            case XIT:
                return 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    int destroyhash();
}



This is the valgrind output:
==68577== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==68577== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==68577== Using Valgrind-3.22.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==68577== Command: ./myprog arg1 arg2
==68577== Parent PID: 37429
==68577== 
==68577== 
==68577== HEAP SUMMARY:
==68577==     in use at exit: 160 bytes in 4 blocks
==68577==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 3 frees, 2,248 bytes allocated
==68577== 
==68577== 160 bytes in 4 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==68577==    at 0x4846828: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==68577==    by 0x1095C6: addRec (in /home/biggmacbilly/adv_C/hash/myprog)
==68577==    by 0x10938E: main (in /home/biggmacbilly/adv_C/hash/myprog)
==68577== 
==68577== LEAK SUMMARY:
==68577==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==68577==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==68577==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==68577==    still reachable: 160 bytes in 4 blocks
==68577==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==68577== 
==68577== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==68577== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)


The valgrind output is showing that I have memory leaks in addrec and main functions. This is my first time working with valgrind and I am not able to figure the memory leaks in the given program. How can I fix these memory leaks? Thank you in advance.
valgrind command: valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --log-file="output.txt" ./myprog
compiler used: GCC

int destroyhash(); at the end of main() is a declaration that such a function exists. destroyhash(); would be the call that you actually intended. Also note that your destroyhash() does not return a value. It should be changed either to do so or defined as  void destroyhash() instead. You should turn up your compiler warning levels so that you will be warned of such things.

"addrec and main functions" => addrec called from main function

There are no memory leaks in that valgrind log. Reachable memory is by definition not leaking.

In addition to Avi's comment, when you do return 0;, destroyhash() where you have it doesn't get a chance to run.

It's an aside, but strongly suggest you avoid global variables.

@Shawn non-deallocated memory if you prefer. This can still be a problem and shouldn't be blindly ignored.

As usual reinventing square wheels in C turns out to be a problem.
Use C++ and std::unordered_map. You will need a quarter of the code and C++'s RAII will make it more difficult for your code to leak. A similar argument would apply to Rust, though that's a bigger step.
As said in the comments, you aren't calling destroyhash().
Additionally I don't see any way out of your 'while (1)' loop other than hitting '5' for XIT. That returns from main. So as far as I can tell the place where you put 'destroyhash()' is unreachable.
The following should do the job:
            case XIT:
                destroyhash();
                return 0;

